# How to use ANT Design Menu.Item and Upload components in place?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx, antd

I use React + Typescript + ANT Design

I am making a menu in which one of the items is responsible for import, but in this case the menu item does not look correct:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<Menu.ItemGroup title={"Actions"}>
     <Menu.Item onClick={}><Icon type="save"/>{"Save"}</Menu.Item>
     <Menu.Item onClick={}><Icon type="delete"/>{"Delete"}</Menu.Item>
     <Upload customRequest={} showUploadList={false} accept=".txt">
           <Menu.Item onClick={}><Icon type="import"/>{"Import"}</Menu.Item>
     </Upload>
     <Menu.Item onClick={}><Icon type="export"/>{"Export"}</Menu.Item>
</Menu.ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try switching the order of usage at `<Upload>` and `<Menu.Item>` components:

```
<Menu.ItemGroup title={"Actions"}>
     <Menu.Item onClick={}><Icon type="save">{"Save"}</Menu.Item>
     <Menu.Item onClick={}><Icon type="delete">{"Delete"}</Menu.Item>
     <Menu.Item onClick={}><Icon type="import">
        <Upload customRequest={} showUploadList={false} accept=".txt">
           {"Import"}
        </Upload>
     </Menu.Item>
     <Menu.Item onClick={}><Icon type="export">{"Export"}</Menu.Item>
</Menu.ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This solution is not good because the upload button will not cover the whole <Menu.Item />.